# Toggle synaptic touchpad with double tap on a corner

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I've got a new [HP G42](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/in/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329744-3848802-3848802-4247520-4296658.html) and it features an LED indicator on the touch-pad’s top left corner and (in Windows, with the vendor's driver) it allowed me to tap twice in that corner to toggle the touchpad and it would indicate me the status via that led.

Can I get this to work this way with Ubuntu?

Comment: cidious's answer seems to be the only way to really get it working. as an alternative i'd suggest defining an unused hotkey to switch the pad on/off.

Comment: do you still have this problem?

Comment: @ElderGeek, yes!

Comment: Which G42 do you have? It appears that there are 3 versions. I'm not sure it's relevant, but I'd rather have too much information than not enough.

Comment: Oh... I'd have to look that up. I didn't knew they came that way. I bought mine a couple of years ago.

Comment: @ElderGeek As this is April 2011 and likely Ubuntu 10.04 that hit EOL in 2015 do you think we can close this as "Un-reproducible"?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That makes sense to me, when adding in that the OP never did provide any information to narrow down the question and the answers have already been deleted there doesn't appear to be any remaining value to this question.

Comment: Never got around to get more details or debug information. +1 on closing this.